# Connecting Spring Boot web app to a postgresql server

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I'm making a web application using Spring Boot and I have the functionality I want by using a in memory database(H2) but I can't connect it to the postgresql server I set up on my computer. I've been at this for some time and tried a bunch of stuff that didn't work so I set everything back to the way it was just to get it working again.

Here's my UploadController.java, it handles the upload from the server and puts it into my in memory database:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import project.service.MediaFile;
import project.service.MediaFileRepository;

@Controller
public class UploadController {

    @Autowired
    private MediaFileRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadmedia", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String uploadForm() {
        return "upload";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadmedia", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadSubmit(@RequestParam(value="files[]") MultipartFile[] files,
                               @RequestParam("tags") String tags, @RequestParam("type") String type)
    {
        String[] tagsArray = tags.split("\\s+");
        MultipartFile file;
        String name;
        String tag;
        String path;

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            file = files[i];
            name = file.getOriginalFilename();
            path = "/Users/johannesthorkell/Developer/spring_prufa/images/" + name;
            System.out.println(name);

            if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                    BufferedOutputStream stream =
                            new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
                    stream.write(bytes);
                    stream.close();
                    for (int j = 0; j < tagsArray.length; j++) {
                        tag = tagsArray[j].toLowerCase();
                        repository.save(new MediaFile(name, tag, path, type));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Failure... " + e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No file");
            }
        }
        return "upload";
    }
}
```

...and here's my MediaFile class, the @Entity object:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MediaFile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String tag;
    private String resource;
    private String type;

    protected MediaFile() {}

    public MediaFile(String name, String tag, String resource, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tag = tag;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "MediaFile[id=%d, name='%s', tag='%s', resource='%s', type='%s']",
                id, name, tag, resource, type);
    }

}
```

...here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HBV501G</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Web_MVC</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

...and finally, here's the application.properties:

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
multipart.maxFileSize=-1
```

With this setup everything works. I tried putting the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
```

...Along with adding the following dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

...And then I tried mixing and matching these things and reading tutorials for a few hours to no avail.

Edit:

I removed one line and added another (at the advice of  Stéphane Nicoll) so now my application.properties look like this:

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix=.jsp
multipart.maxFileSize=-1
debug=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
```

...And my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HBV501G</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Web_MVC</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

With the changes to my application.properties my app now runs! But I get the following error when I submit to my POST form to UploadController.java:

```
2015-10-06 11:32:14.878  INFO 22287 --- [           main] project.Application                      : Started Application in 11.897 seconds (JVM running for 12.971)
2015-10-06 11:32:40.263  INFO 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-10-06 11:32:40.264  INFO 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-10-06 11:32:40.295  INFO 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 31 ms
hopaskipting.pdf
2015-10-06 11:32:49.752 DEBUG 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2015-10-06 11:32:49.760  WARN 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2015-10-06 11:32:49.760 ERROR 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
Failure... could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I changed the GenerationType to IDENTITY and get the following error:

```
2015-10-06 12:56:32.496 DEBUG 22746 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into media_file (name, resource, tag, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-10-06 12:56:32.505 DEBUG 22746 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into media_file (name, resource, tag, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Failure... A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [project.service.MediaFile#0]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [project.service.MediaFile#0]
```

Comment: What failure do you see when you try to use Postgres?

Comment: You don't need to specify the driver, it's auto-detected. You should also add "--debug" when you start your app (or put debug in `application.properties`) which will show the auto-configuration report. It will tell you exactly what was enabled/disabled and why.

Comment: @StépaneNicoll I made your proposed changes and now my app actually runs but it still fails when I try to put my data in the db. I added both the application.properties and pom.xml as the look now along with the error I get to the main post and I posted an answer to my question which has the auto-configuration report as it didn't fit in my main post.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I updated my post with the Error message I get (at the bottom).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key part of the error is:

```
2015-10-06 11:32:49.760 ERROR 22287 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
```

Hibernate's looking for a table named `hibernate_sequence` to support `@GeneratedValue` on `MediaFile`. You've configured it with `AUTO` at the moment. The actual behaviour then varies depending on the database you're using.

I think you have a couple of options:

1. Create a sequence in Postgres (`CREATE SEQUENCE`), named `hibernate_sequence`
2. Change to using a different generation type, e.g. `GenerationType.IDENTITY`

Comment: I changed the generation type to identity and changed my relation in accordance with the error messages I received but I'm stuck on another error that I put in the OP. Am I not generating the id correctly?

Comment: I think that would be better tackled in a separate question, it doesn't have anything to do with connecting to Postgres.

Comment: I could kiss you... this was driving me nuts, thanks so much again. I'd upvote you a lot more if I could:)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd create my own dataSource bean, like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("myapp.dataSource.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("myapp.dataSource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("myapp.dataSource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("myapp.dataSource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
logging.level. = INFO

myapp.dataSource.driver = 
myapp.dataSource.url = 
myapp.dataSource.username = 
myapp.dataSource.password =
```

IF you don't want to try this, you could try changing your driver **org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver** to **org.postgresql.Driver**.

It's hard to help without any logs.